# Is that possible to change timeZoneInfo in mongod.conf?

Tags: mongodb

This is my `/etc/mongod.conf` in a CentOS environment:

```
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

When I change it to `timeZoneInfo` to `timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran` and restart the service, it doesn't start but has no errors, neither `journalctl -xef | grep mongo`, nor `tailf /var/log/mongod/mongod.log`.

The time of my server is `Asia/Tehran`, but I want to make sure `mongodb`'s time is Tehran too.

I should mention that I read the documentations of MongoDB and reading some other answers in StackOverFlow and articles in other website that MongoDB stores in UTC by default, but my application can send the date and time in my preferred date.

Is that possible to change this option? Or since my application uses the value of `$(date)` of my server, I can leave that option unchanged?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to make sure mongodb's time is Tehran"? All `Date` objects in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - **always and only!** If you like to display the time as local time, then you must do in in your application or use functions like `$dateToString`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. So you mean if we suppose now UTC time is 12 PM and Tehran is 03:30, then if I store a client's purchase date like `2023-05-07 15:30`, this stored date is in UTC logically, but the time I see is in Tehran time. I hope I asked clear. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works usually. Many client applications shows time as local time, sometimes you can define it in the settings.